# How to rig up temporary steps?

Tags: carpentry, steps

My yurt is up, but I need some steps.

The deck is 32" above grade. Eventually I'll build a landing / small deck, but I'm too busy with other projects right now (like closing in the yurt wall canvas!)

What can I do to put together some simple, temporary steps until I get around to doing it right?

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with what you're asking, but is that gap between the joists under the hinge side of the door something to be concerned about?

Comment: @NiallC: Those aren't joists, those are 1'-wide strips of 3/8" plywood, bent around the perimeter of the round deck. The bottom edge flares outward slightly, leaving that unsightly gap. Later I may add cleats to pull them together, but only for appearance.

Answer (score 8):

Jay, why not get a couple of precut stringers and 2X12 theads?  Put a 1X riser on the front, a 1X nailer on the top back and screw it to the building.  You can fancy it up later and use the same stringers.

Comment: I had no idea you could buy precut stringers - I was assuming I would have to do this from scratch. I'll check 'em out.

Comment: off the shelf at any box store.